# How to get access to a directive attrs with isolated scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to have access to model created by directive and in the same time I need to get attrs in the directive.

JS:

```
module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){
 return {            
   scope: {        
     name: '=Name' // Dynamically created ng-model in the directive element
   },
   link: function(scope, element, attrs){
     attrs.$observe('createControl', function(){
       attrs.createControl //is empty if scope is an object, otherwise it is passed from html attribute
     }
   }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="control-group" ng-repeat="x in selectedControls">
  <div create-control="{{ x }}"></div>
</div>
```

If `scope` is defined as an object, `attrs` is empty, otherwise it is value passed from html.

What the cause of this behavior? How to get access to a passed attrs and to a models?

Comment: The `'=Name` syntax requires that your HTML has a `Name` attribute.  E.g., `<div create-control="{{ x }}" Name="???"></div>`

Comment: `=Name` attribute dynamically added in the directive html. So yes it is exists. Furthermore I can get it. The problem with the `attrs`.

Comment: @I159 Can you include your directive HTML where you say Name is dynamically added?

Comment: With an isolate scope, try `scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.createControl, function(value) { ... })` instead and see how that works for you. Ideally with an isolate scope you'd pass it in as one of the scope parameters, e.g. `createControl: '@'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:** `create-control` needs to evaluate `{{x}}` within the parent scope, but by making the `scope` an object when the directive is declared you create an isolate scope. This means that `attrs.createControl` doesn't have access to `x`. Therefore, it is empty.

**One solution:** You can fix this several ways, the best of which is to configure your directive to accept `scope.createControl` into its isolate scope through an attribute.

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pvtpenguin/tABt6/

```
myApp.directive('createControl', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: '@', // Dynamically created ng-model in the directive element
            createControl: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('createControl', function () {
                // the following two statements are equivalent
                console.log(attrs.createControl);
                console.log(scope.createControl);
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Matt but the following two statements are equivalent only if the attrs is set.

> console.log(attrs.createControl);
>
> console.log(scope.createControl);

Otherwise, `attrs.createControl` will be undefined but `scope.createControl` will have a function defined.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have access to model created by directive

```
module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){

    return {            
        ...
        require:'ngModel',
        link:function(scope, element, attrs, ngMdlCntrl){
            //You have the access to the model of your directive here thr. ngMdlCntrl
        }
        ...
    }})
```

The require `ng-model` is for the model at you are setting dynamically.