# AngularJS: How to access scope from directive

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using a directive to draw graphs:

```
drawGraph.directive "graph", ->
  restrict: "E" # Use as element
  scope: # Isolate scope
    data: "=" # Two-way bind data to local scope
    opts: "=?" # '?' means optional

  template: "<div></div><div id='{{graph.id}}'></div>" # We need a div to attach graph to
  link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
    graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts)
```

While

```
<div id='{{graph.id}}'>
```

actually works in the partial, it returns

```
<div id></div>
```

when I use it in the template of the directive. Can anyone tell me why?

**Update:**

After the hint of @Marek, my directive now looks like this:

```
drawGraph.directive "graph", ->
    restrict: "E" # Use as element
    scope: # Isolate scope
        data: "=" # Two-way bind data to local scope
        opts: "=?" # '?' means optional

    template: "<div></div><div class='legend'></div>" # We need a div to attach graph to
    link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        scope.opts.labelsDiv = elem.children()[0].getElementsByClassName("legend")[0]
        scope.graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts)
```

Options are added in the controller:

```
drawGraph.controller "MyCtrl", [ "myService", "$scope", (myService, $scope) -> 
    myService.async().then (d) ->
        rawData = d
        group = rawData

        i = 0
        while i < group.length
            j = 0
            while j < group[i].data.length
            # Convert date
            tmp = new Date(group[i].data[j][0])
            group[i].data[j][0] = tmp
            # Set draw options
            group[i].opts = 
                labels: [ "x", "Your Price", "Market Price" ],
                customBars: true,
                labelsSeparateLines: "true",
                hideOverlayOnMouseOut: false,
                legend: "always",
                showRangeSelector: true,
                xAxisLabelWidth: 80,
            ++j
        ++i
$scope.graphs = group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that an isolated scope can't access the parent scope by default, so "id" needs to be defined in the scope of the directive.

```
drawGraph.directive "graph", [(graph) ->
restrict: "E"
scope:
    data: "="
    opts: "=?"
    id: "="
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually putting the graph into the scope.
The last line should be:

**scope.graph** = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts)

Comment: Thanks @Marek for your answer, but unfortunately that doesn't work: It's still "<div id></div>".

Comment: Okay, I took a look at the dygraph library and as I saw the object that Dygraph constructor returns doesn't contain id property. Good thing is that you don't need one. Take a look here http://plnkr.co/edit/Al06fWr0Ib8H7BIr5Dbi?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort @Marek. You need an ID when you want to separate the legend from the graph: http://dygraphs.com/options.html#Legend "labelsDiv", which is what I want to achieve. I also feel like I'm missing some fundamental understanding of scopes and directives somehow here.

Comment: In the labelsDiv you can pass element instead of id. I updated that plunk to match that case: http://plnkr.co/edit/Al06fWr0Ib8H7BIr5Dbi?p=preview There is lot of nasty stuff around scopes and directives but also great possibilities. Be sure to check the angular documentation. :)

Comment: Thanks @Marek, tried that - see update above. However, console says "labelsDiv: undefined", which I think could be related to the fact that I'm setting the other options in the controller. I also guess there must be a more "angular" way of making the interpolation of scopes work. You mentioned the doc, I of course read it, but unfortunately I'm too new to AngularJS and not super experienced, I just don't get it I fear :(.

Comment: There are some other answers on SO that I think are dealing with the same issue, but unfortunately I can't make it work with my code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421111/how-to-get-access-to-a-directive-attrs-with-isolated-scope?rq=1 and (much longer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914213/when-writing-a-directive-how-do-i-decide-if-a-need-no-new-scope-a-new-child-sc?rq=1 for instance.